# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on else clause

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to fetch records from Database and on clicking a link it passes parameter to take to the desired url. but when I click in the link i get the following error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/next/public_html/cms/index.php on line 31

the code used is:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');

    require_once('includes/class-query.php');

    if ( !empty ( $_GET ) ) {
        if ( !empty ( $_GET['p'] ) ) {
            $post = $_GET['p'];
        }

        if ( !empty ( $_GET['cat'] ) ) {
            $cat = $_GET['cat'];
        }
    }

    if ( empty ( $post ) && empty ( $cat ) ) {
        $posts_array = $query->all_posts();
    } elseif ( !empty ( $post ) ) {
        $posts_array = $query->post($post);
    } elseif ( !empty ( $cat ) ) {
        echo 'cat';
    } ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php foreach ( $posts_array as $post ) : ?>
            <div class="post">
                <h1><a href="?p=<?php echo $post->ID; ?>"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></a></h1>
                <p><?php echo $post->post_content; ?></p>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your query failed and you need to find out why. Check for errors for db and in PHP.

Comment: place echos (`echo "failed";`) throughout your conditional statements and see what pops in there. You can track/troubleshoot it that way, along with using print_r and/or var_dump

Comment: I'm pretty sure a `<?php print_r($posts_array); ?>` reaveals the problem. Probably `$posts_array` is not an array.

Comment: `$posts_array = $query->post($post);` looks as if it's only returning a single post, as such attempting to iterate over it will cause that error because it's not an array.

Comment: <?php print_r($posts_array); ?> returns array

Comment: thanks all for your help...i found the problem...actually i passed ID(capital) instead of id(small) hence variable was not getting detected.

Answer (score 1):

The failure case of this code is when $cat is defined. Adding to @Mohammad Imran Ashraf's suggestion if you write something like this the error will go away.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');

    require_once('includes/class-query.php');

    if ( !empty ( $_GET ) ) {
        if ( !empty ( $_GET['p'] ) ) {
            $post = $_GET['p'];
        }

        if ( !empty ( $_GET['cat'] ) ) {
            $cat = $_GET['cat'];
        }
    }

    if ( empty ( $post ) && empty ( $cat ) ) {
        $posts_array = $query->all_posts();
    } elseif ( !empty ( $post ) ) {
        $posts_array = $query->post($post);
    } elseif ( !empty ( $cat ) ) {
        $posts_array = array();
    } ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php foreach ( $posts_array as $post ) : ?>
            <div class="post">
                <h1><a href="?p=<?php echo $post->ID; ?>"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></a></h1>
                <p><?php echo $post->post_content; ?></p>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

or

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');

    require_once('includes/class-query.php');

    if ( !empty ( $_GET ) ) {
        if ( !empty ( $_GET['p'] ) ) {
            $post = $_GET['p'];
        }

        if ( !empty ( $_GET['cat'] ) ) {
            $cat = $_GET['cat'];
        }
    }

    $posts_array = array();
    if ( empty ( $post ) && empty ( $cat ) ) {
        $posts_array = $query->all_posts();
    } elseif ( !empty ( $post ) ) {
        $posts_array = $query->post($post);
    } elseif ( !empty ( $cat ) ) {
        echo "cat";
    } ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php foreach ( $posts_array as $post ) : ?>
            <div class="post">
                <h1><a href="?p=<?php echo $post->ID; ?>"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></a></h1>
                <p><?php echo $post->post_content; ?></p>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any of the two solutions will work. Hope it helps. The root cause is the uninitialised array `$posts_array`. So either initialise it at the first hand or assign it a value in the else clause.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an array in the last else because you are returning an array in other two if, and foreach loop using that array.

**Change this code**

```
if ( empty ( $post ) && empty ( $cat ) ) {
        $posts_array = $query->all_posts();
    } elseif ( !empty ( $post ) ) {
        $posts_array = $query->post($post);
    } elseif ( !empty ( $cat ) ) {

     //Change this line and pass an array instead of echo something

        echo 'cat';
    }
```

Comment: how to do that? because the result of <?php print_r($posts_array); ?> is an array

Comment: Thats what I'm saying, you need to change this code, i did not change, I just mentioned that line in which you need to make change. Don't echo something, pass an array instead of echo.